# How to disable warning using a pragma with intel c++ compiler

Tags: icc

I cannot find a reliable document on how to avoid warnings with a pragma.
The [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514587) says that the warning pragma is compatible with Microsoft compiler so it should be:

```
#pragma warning ( push )
#pragma warning ( disable:1234 )
#pragma warning ( pop )
```

which is not working with `icc (ICC) 15.0.3 20150407` on a GNU/Linux system.

However, what is working is:

```
#pragma warning disable 1234
```

I could not find any working syntax for the push/pop however.
Does somebody know where to look to get some official documentation about that?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thinking I was seeing the same problem. However, further investigation showed that icpc 2015 was following Microsoft #pragma warning push and pop syntax. The reason I initially thought it was not is that the warnings were not coming from the header I had wrapped with the push/pop but from the instantiation of a template function.
See David's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227420/how-to-use-gcc-diagnostic-pragma-with-c-template-functions#6227937).